# How to get age based on month/day/year dropdown in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the age of users based on the month date and year field they enter in the dropdown. This is working in **Chrome** and other browsers but in **Firefox** I get an Invalid Date Error:

```js
jQuery('#cons_birth_date_YEAR,#cons_birth_date_MONTH,#cons_birth_date_DAY').on('change',function(){
    
    var selectedYear=$('#cons_birth_date_YEAR').find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedDay=$('#cons_birth_date_DAY').find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedMonth=$('#cons_birth_date_MONTH').find('option:selected').val();
  
    if(selectedYear!=0 && selectedMonth!=0 && selectedDay!=0)
    {
        
        var today = new Date();
        var dob=new Date(selectedDay+"/"+selectedMonth+"/"+selectedYear);
        console.log(dob);
        var age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() -1970;
        $("#age").val(age);
    }


                if (age < 13) {
 alert('under 13');

}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<legend>

<span class="aural-only cons_dob"></span>
<span class="input-label survey-question-label cons_dob">Date of Birth:</span>
</legend>
<span class="input-container">
<span id="cons_birth_date_date" title="Date:">

<select name="cons_birth_date_MONTH" id="cons_birth_date_MONTH" title="Month">


<option value="0">Month

</option>

<option value="1" selected="selected">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
<option value="9">Sep</option>
<option value="10">Oct</option>
<option value="11">Nov</option>
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>

<select name="cons_birth_date_DAY" id="cons_birth_date_DAY" title="Day">


<option value="0">Day

</option>

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="cons_birth_date_YEAR" id="cons_birth_date_YEAR" title="Year">


<option value="0">Year

</option>

<option value="1997" selected="selected">1997</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>


</select>
</span>
</span>
</fieldset>
```

This script adds an alert if a user is under 13 years of age. This works in Chrome but in Firefox, the line below is returning the error: Invalid Date

```
var dob=new Date(selectedDay+"/"+selectedMonth+"/"+selectedYear);
```

Comment: Please verify that the selectedDay, selectedMonth and selectedYear have the correct value. Instead of doing $('#cons_birth_date_YEAR').find('option:selected').val() a better way is to do just $('#cons_birth_date_YEAR').val() when reading selected value of a select element.

Comment: The selectedDay, selectedMonth, selectedYear are already pulling the correct value. The issue comes in this line var dob=new Date(selectedDay+"/"+selectedMonth+"/"+selectedYear);

Comment: Yes, as @Roy mentioned and documented in several places the new Date(string) works differently in different browsers, specially when the dates does not have leading zeros. I'd suggest using new Date(year, month, day) format and remember the months are zero-index based meaning Jan=0 and Feb=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
 var dateSTR = "2019-07-02";
 var dob = new Date(dateSTR.replace(/-/g,"/"));
```

You can [read this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/cross-browser-crazy-44e90d61b204) and check the crossbrowsing problems.

Comment: Ah ok, I tested this in console and it works. I will just need to rework things a bit to make this fit.